# Reading from a text file resource which is compiled into a .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

I try to create a simple application which reads out from a "resource" file, which I've already add into my solution. I've tried this, but this doesn't work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetContentStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myfile.txt", UriKind.Absolute));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(streamResourceInfo.Stream);
    var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

It says: "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified."

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you check [how to read embedded ressource file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file) ? I think this should help you out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My final solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stream stream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TheNameOfMyProject.TheNameOfSubFolder.file.txt");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(content);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```